# PHP 8: How to avoid fatal error when passing non-countable values to count function?

Tags: php, php-8

So I upgraded to PHP 8 and ran my script which gave me this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\includes\functions\create_session.php:78 
> Stack trace: 
> #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\public\front_desk.php(508): Session->check_subfeature_access(22, 0) 
> #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\includes\functions\create_session.php on line 78

Which turned out to be due to a new update in PHP 8 that doesn't allow non-array values to be used in the count function and throws a fatal error stopping the further script execution. For example, if you have a `$_POST['checkboxes_checked']` and you do `count($_POST['checkboxes_checked'])` then it will give the above error because by default it doesn't recognize it as an array. To fix this error, you can do: `count((array)$_POST['checkboxes_checked']))`, which fixes the problem.

However, the problem in my case is that I have a couple of hundred files that need this problem fixed, I don't want to go inside each file and fix this as that would be extremely time-consuming. Is there a way to configure PHP 8 to ignore this and still proceed with the count function with these $_POST parameters? or some sort of search/replace regex that I can run on all files that replace `count($_POST['some_parameter_name'])` with `count((array)$_POST['some_parameter_name']))`? Honestly, I have no idea how I can fix this problem without manually going into each file, and this is the part where I need your help.

Comment: Errr, `$_POST` is an array but there is no reason to assume `$_POST['checkboxes_checked']` if an array, because is no checkboxes are checked it wont even exist. So in fact the issue is sloppy coding

Comment: Similar to RiggsFolly's comment (which appeared a few seconds before I posted mine)... unless you're _expecting_ an array in a specific item of the POST data, why would you try to count it in the first place? Surely when you wrote the code you'd know if it was going to have an array or a single value submitted to it.

Comment: @ADyson Oh I did, however, I iterated through the things that I use `count` for using a for loop, like the number of checkboxes checked, now PHP 8 goes "Sorry fellah, it may be an array for you but since you haven't specified it, I am gonna give you an error".

Comment: _Is there a way to configure PHP 8 to ignore this and still proceed with the count function_ This change to PHP is supposed to stop us developers making these type of sloppy coding mistakes, so I doubt they would have provided a workaround for the sloppy coder :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Hmm, you do have a point there, I just tried the same code and checked no checkboxes and submitted with the PHP 7.3 server, and it turns out, the array doesn't exist, due to no checkboxes clicked with the name of `checkboxes_checked[]`.

Comment: It's as easy as writing better code. In case you expect a param to be array, treat it as one. Otherwise, treat it as whatever you need it.

Comment: Are you saying you expect an array, but the issue comes when no checkboxes were checked and therefore the value is $_POST value isn't there? If so then put an `isset` check before you try to loop. That should always have been the approach anyway really - PHP8 has just made the language less tolerant of this kind of loose coding, in an attempt to drive up quality and reliability in general.

Comment: @CornelRaiu Agreed, I'd slowly start converting the code to the preferred dynamics, but is there no workaround for this at the moment so I can present this as a MVP demo under the deadline?

Comment: @ADyson I have an isset statement before it, so it doesn't really mess up much in most cases.

Comment: Well, the content is `NULL`, that's not countable, it never was, it never will be. Ah, but you knew that, of course. Well, the option I see it to define your own `count()` function, one that does accept `NULL` as an argument. Then all you need to do is replace all the occurrences of `count(` in your code by `myTolerantCount(`, and you're done.

Comment: In what cases _does_ it mess up then? I've you've covered it with an isset then you should be fine - as long as there's at least one item in the array you can count and loop it.

Comment: @ADyson true, but can I reduce the tolerance a little bit somehow temporarily without downgrading or write a regex or something that implements this change in one go on all files in VS Code?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware That actually is a great temporary solution, can you write a brief answer based off of that so I can mark this question as answered?

Comment: `can I reduce the tolerance a little bit somehow temporarily without downgrading or write a regex or something`...without knowing your codebase we can't really comment, we don't know how consistent your style is as to whether you could reliably replace all instances of this usage with something else. KikoSoftware might be onto something - it'd be easier to replace all calls to count with calls to your own function, which wraps count with an additional isset/null type of check. Needs to be 100% temporary though really, it's a bit of a dirty workaround.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Think twice before doing that. You dont want to be responsible for something like that being used all over the web like the dreaded ClearUp() function used as a fake SQL Injection protector :)

Comment: @ADyson I see. However, I would say that in all occurrences I am using count on $_POST it always looks the same as the checkboxes_chexcked example I gave, of course, just with the name change.

Comment: Here's a demo: https://3v4l.org/BBtjo . If you wrap usage of count and/or loops in an isset() you should have no problems. Based on what you've said it's unclear how/where you're getting this error. Maybe there are some instances where you forgot to implement the `isset` test?

Comment: @RiggsFolly XD lol, let him put a warning/don't use in prod sign on top of that. Of course, I myself will only use it for the MVP demo, after that, I'll slowly migrate my code up to the PHP 8 standards.

Comment: @ADyson I didn't use the `isset` inside the for loop but when I am defining the variable, like: `if (isset($_POST['checkboxes_checked') { // define it }` of course, now I get that I should've used it at the right place...

Comment: @RiggsFolly: Haha, yes, that wouldn't be good. I'm just trying to help out with a temporary solution. In the end the people writing or modifying code are responsible for what they do.

Comment: Glad you've got the idea then. `when I am defining the variable`...not sure what variable you're defining or for what purpose, but if you then later directly write `count($_POST['checkboxes_checked')` outside that `isset` block, then you run the risk of it not actually being defined when you try to use it. IMHO that's as much a logic failure than "sloppy" coding per se. So you should certainly be aiming to tidy that up, regardless of the PHP version you're using!

Comment: @ADyson Agreed very much, and thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One temporary solution would be to define your own `count()` function. For instance:

```
/**
 * @deprecated Temporary solution for count() TypeError on invalid countables
 */

function oldCount($input)
{
   return isset($input) && is_array($input) ? count($input) : 0;
}
```

This is just a quick example. You should ideally use your `(array)` prefix.

Now all you need to do is replace all the occurrences of `count(` in your code with `oldCount(`, and you're done.

**WARNING:** This is only meant to be a temporary solution. It requires an extra function call every time it is used and PHP 8 has not incorporated a stricter without reason: It's there to protect you. Update your code as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'd suggest you write a small caution note to not use it in production as this was just a solution to patch a temporary problem.

Comment: I will, I think RiggsFolly has a point there.

Comment: I'd advise to put this doc block above this method:
`/**
* @deprecated
**/`
This will show anyone that this is something temporary which is meant to be replaced later :)
Edit: Submitted too soon by accident ^^

Comment: @Fanmade I added the doc block. Not everybody will be using this type of documentation, but it can't hurt.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Thank you. Yes, I know. But since reading existing code is a big part of programming I learned that providing a little context to anything more complex than a simple getter greatly improves the developer experience. If this doc block is added, proper tools like PhpStorm will even strongly hint to anyone that this method should not be used anymore, which usually helps increasing the code quality in the long term :)

Comment: @Fanmade Agreed, I have a tool setup for myself that warns me of all the things that are tagged \@depracated \@problematic, and a few others in my PHP code whenever I do git commit on my repositories. This way, it will also remind me from time to time and eventually get me to fix it before expected.